# image "pyimage14" doesn't exist

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

```py
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

window = Tk()
name = Label(window, text = 'PythonX -Learn Python', bg = 'white', fg = 'blue', font=('Serif',16))
img = Image.open('OIP.png')
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
image = Label(master = window , image=logo)
btn = Button(window, text = 'Submit')
username = Label(window, text = 'Username', font = ('serif',12))
inputBox = Entry(window)

name.pack()
image.pack()
username.pack(side=LEFT)
inputBox.pack(side=RIGHT)
btn.place(x=100, y=350)
window.mainloop()
```

Here is my code, I get the similar error of `pyimage10 does not exist` so I searched out for solution and someone said use master = window for image object, and after using this I got `pyimage14 does not exist`, which I did not found on Google.

Comment: Do you have more than 1 instance of `Tk()`? Are you creating the images in a function?

Comment: @TheLizzard i have only one instance of Tk();

Comment: @TheLizzard this is the code for image:
```
img = Image.open('OIP.png')
logo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
image = Label(master = window , image=logo)
```

Comment: This can't be your full code because it always starts with `pyimage0`. Are you creating the any of the images in any functions that you defined?

Comment: this is the code i wrote till now just simple GUI, for image input field btn

Comment: @TheLizzard can you share some info about what are these pyimage0 pyimage10 pyimage14, I am complete beginner to tkinter?

Comment: Given code will not create such errors.

Comment: @RakeshKumar Every time you create a new `tkinter` image using `PIL`, a name must be chosen for the image. `PIL` (by default) picks `pyimage<number>` where the number starts from 0 and increments. No image names can be reused. As CoolCloud mentioned the code you posted doesn't give that error. I think that you should post more code.

Comment: Did you *import* this script from another Python script?

Comment: i followed it using some learning application.